# Python boto 3 - download a file from S3 and reupload to a new folder

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to download a file from a lambda and reupload it then to a new folder.

```
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_resource.Bucket('mybucket').download_file('hello.txt', '/tmp/hello.txt')
```

I have given the lambda full S3 access but still getting an access denied error

`"errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied",`

Comment: Have you provided service credentials? Is the bucket accessible by a public endpoint?

Comment: I usually don't need to provide credentials with these clients when the bucket is in the same account

Comment: What is your lambda's execution role?

Comment: Is the bucket KMS SSE encrypted, if so: does the lambda have access to the respective key?

Comment: It was the KMS thanks! Add an answer if you like I will accept it

Comment: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied The KMs permissions did not solve this when trying to upload though any ideas?

Comment: well, what KMS permissions did you give the lambda now? What key policy does the associated KMS key have?

Comment: Got it sorted it was a typo in the bucket name, I can accept an answer if you post it saying to check the KMS permissions